# Using FFmpeg in Unity WebPlayer

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, unity-game-engine

Has anyone use FFmpeg successfully in Unity **WebPlayer**? I need to play MP3 in WebPlayer.

BTW, Can javascript in browser save the binary file to local position?

Thanks!

Comment: That seem to be two separate questions...

Comment: @Samoth I came up with second question because I was thinking if it is possible to save the MP3 to local position, then load it with WWW.

Comment: The MP3 is downloaded when the Unity is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem without FFmpeg.

I convert the MP3 byte[] to Base64, pass it to browser, and play it using:

```
<audio src="data:audio/mp3;base64,{{audio}}"></audio>
```